# Arrange in order a concat date string

Tags: sql

I need help with this date string

This is the current string I have: 08/01/2022, 06/23/2022 in one cell (The format is MM/DD/YYY)

How can I get a result like this: 06/23/2022, 08/01/2022 with SQL

[image]

Comment: Please tag only the **single** RDBMS you want your result in!

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags, feel free to add the correct one back.

Answer (score 0):

See query below done in BigQuery:

```
with sample_data as (
  select "08/01/2022, 06/23/2022" as date_test
),
sort_val as (
select 
  format_date("%m/%d/%Y",(parse_date("%m/%d/%Y",d))) as sorted
from sample_data,
unnest(split(date_test, ", ")) as d
order by sorted asc
)
select 
  string_agg(cast(sorted as STRING),",") as date_test
from sort_val
```

Output:

[image]